# Removing a python3 reference from python3.11's sys.path

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install Python 3.11 on my Ubuntu 18 machine.
I understand that Ubuntu heavily uses the `python3` keyword, which is mapped to a Python 3.6.9 instance, and so I cannot override it.

It seems that `python3` is inserted automatically into `sys.path` in Python3.11. When I run `python3.11 -m site` I get

```
sys.path = [
    '/usr/lib/python3.11',
    '/home/ubuntu/utils',
    '/usr/lib/python311.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3.11/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

(`/home/ubuntu/utils` is the only content in my `$PYTHONPATH`).

When I print `sys.path` in `python3.11 -S` mode I get:

```
['', '/', '/home/ubuntu/utils', '/home/ubuntu/utils', '/usr/lib/python311.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.11', '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload']
```

I am mostly concerned with `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, as it seems that it tries to take Python 3.6 packages and use them.

As an example, I was able to get `pip`, but it looks at the python3 directory, and so it doesnt let me install packages:

```
$ python3.11 -m pip install IPython
Keyring is skipped due to an exception: module 'collections' has no attribute 'MutableMapping'
Requirement already satisfied: IPython in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from IPython) (4.2.1)
```

(Yet, when I run `python3.11 -m IPython`, I see it accesses `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython` and fails due to a SyntaxError.)

I tried editing the `/usr/lib/python3.11/site.py` file, but it doesn't seem to change anything (and `print` statements that I inserted there went ignored).

Comment: Are you installing Python 3.11 as root/with sudo? Don't do that: it will mess up your system.

Comment: @9769953 Yeah, it's a remote VPS and root is the only user on the system

Comment: Still, don't put it in the system path. Use `/usr/local` (which is what that directory is for), or create `/opt/local`, or put it even in `/root/.local` or so. I prefer `/opt/local`, to differentiate it clearly from the system.

Comment: I hope you can remove the current 3.11 installation, without harming the existing 3.6 installation (including reverting `site.py`). After re-installation in another, safer, directory, see if you still have sys.path problems.

Comment: If root is the only user, it might be good to create a regular user (with or without sudo access), and use that user for doing normal things, such as `python3.11 -m IPython`. You could make make `/opt/local` owned by that normal user, and thus avoid using root completely, keeping things safer.

Comment: @9769953 Thanks, I'm not sure though how does one install it in a different directory? I've got a couple of app folders in `/opt` and I have no `/opt/local`. Can you please explain it in a bit more detail?

Comment: How did you install 3.11 in the first place?

Comment: `app install python3.11 python3.11-distutils`

Comment: Then I take it you added an extra repository for aptitude to find 3.11?

Comment: Yes: `add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`

Comment: Ok, simple solution: uninstall and don't use 3.11 on Ubuntu 18.04. Python 3.11 is not even properly out yet, but a release candidate. If you want the latest-greatest, use an up-to-date OS (or even e.g. Arch, to be always up-to-date).

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty sure 3.10 had the same problem for me, so you're saying that given I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 I should stick to the 3.6 it has built in?

Comment: Sorry for not having actual helpful advice, but given your comments, the level of explanation needed to install 3.11 on 18.04 would be at a beginner's level, and that would be far too long for a decent answer (plus more suitable on e.g. superuser.com). Hence I'm advising you to not burn your hands with this kind of thing. Unless, of course, you want to play around and learn system administration, but then you'll have more reading up to do.

Comment: Yes, stick to 3.6. But if you can, upgrade/replace the whole OS to a newer version (20.04 and 22.04 are LTS versions with more recent software).

Comment: @ronash: Have a look at [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). No need to upgrade your OS just to use a newer Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple, maybe not the pretty one - use virtualenv.

I'm also using `ppa:deadsnakes/ppa`, and yes, if you use it directly it will include packages from system python3.

I will appreciate explanation for this behavior, but here's my workaround:

```bash
# to test it on a clean system
docker run -it --rm ubuntu:22.04
```

Reproduce issue

```bash
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

# Add python3.11 as system package
apt-get update
apt-get -y install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
apt-get -y install python3.11-dev

python3.11 -m site
```

Output (note `'/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages'` in sys.path):

```
sys.path = [
    '/',
    '/usr/lib/python311.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.11',
    '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Fix:

```bash
# Add virtualenv
apt-get -y install python3.11-venv
python3.11 -m venv /opt/venv

/opt/venv/bin/python3.11 -m site
```

Output (note clean `sys.path`):

```
sys.path = [
    '/',
    '/usr/lib/python311.zip',
    '/usr/lib/python3.11',
    '/usr/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload',
    '/opt/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: False
```

---

P.S. I will not explain how to activate and use virtualenv - it's basics, next step will be this article, how to use python from virtualenv "without activating" it: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/activate-virtualenv-dockerfile/